# scp folder structure and only files with a specific extension

Tags: macos, fedora, scp

I have a huge folder structure with deep subfolders, and inside these folders there is files with different extensions (`.txt, .pdf, ...`).

what i want to do is to copy the whole folder structure along with the files with only the `.pdf` extension.

I'm using `scp` but there is no option to specify which extension to copy.

i tried `rsync` with exclude and include options but it also did not worked and the shell window forze

P.S: I'm on `MacOSX` Mountain Lion and i'm trying to copy from `Fedora` 16

what is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rsync -rav -e ssh --include '*/' --include='*.pdf' --exclude='*' server:path localpathpath
```